# For excel i need formula to calculate estimate end time

Tags: excel

Suppose  i have given 90 data entry to person but 15 entry can be done in 1 hour and i have start time 08:00 am . I am finding a formula for end time . 
Cell a1 data entry 90
Cell b1 start           08:00 am
Cell c1 estimate end time ?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code service you have to try by your own see : [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give another cell with entries per hour, lets say d1.
Than the formula will be:
"=TIME(HOUR(b1)+a1/d1; MINUTE(B1);0)"
This will calculate your end of work to 14:00

Comment: Thank you very much friend. With the help of your given formula i had find single cell formula--------"= (TIME(HOUR(B2), MINUTE(B2), SECOND(B2)) + (TIME(0,4,0) * A2))".. hope next time also i get help from you